# Custom roles can't access to wp-admin

Tags: functions, wp-admin, user-roles

i'm trying to create a custom role, very similar to admin but without the capabilities to edit/delete plugins.
Since i don't wont to use plugin for that i've edited the functions.php file adding something like this:

```
// Add a custom user role

$result = add_role( 'new_role', __(
'New Role' ),
array( 
'edit_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit their own posts
'edit_pages' => true, // Allows user to edit pages
'edit_others_posts' => true, // Allows user to edit others posts not just their own
'create_posts' => true, // Allows user to create new posts
'manage_categories' => true, // Allows user to manage post categories
'publish_posts' => true, // Allows the user to publish, otherwise posts stays in draft mode
'edit_themes' => true, // false denies this capability. User can’t edit your theme
'install_plugins' => false, // User cant add new plugins
'update_plugin' => true, // User can’t update any plugins
'update_core' => false // user cant perform core updates
)
                  );
```

After that i can create with my admin profile a new user and assign him the role i just created.
All good untill the moment i log in with the new user when i have only access to the front page of the website.

I tried to add /wp-admin after the url but i get the message:

*Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.*

I've tried to add this line in the array above

```
'manage_options' => true, //not sure about that
```

but without success, the block remains

**Question: How i can, without installing plugins, make a custom user role access the control panel?**

Thanks, y'all

Answer (score 0):

With help of following code you can make a custom user role access the control panel. Following code works on hooks `admin_init` or `init`

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_custom_function' );

function my_custom_function() {

  add_role( 'new_role', 'New Role' );
  
  $role = get_role( 'new_role' );
  
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_posts' );
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_pages' );
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_others_posts' );
  $role->add_cap( 'create_posts' );
  $role->add_cap( 'manage_categories' );
  $role->add_cap( 'publish_posts' );
  $role->add_cap( 'edit_themes' );
  $role->add_cap( 'install_plugins', false );
  $role->add_cap( 'update_plugin' );
  $role->add_cap( 'update_core', false );
 
  // add more capabilities as per you requirements
}
```

Comment: Isn't add_role a one-time operation that updates the database? I don't think you need to run it on every admin page load.